# How do you extract data from a javascript object when you don’t know the name of the property field because it was is a hashmap object in java?

Tags: javascript, json, hashmap

How do you extract specific data from a javascript object when you don’t know the name of the property field because it is an object that was converted from a hashmap in java?

In my case, I created a Hashmap object in java and using the put method, I put into this object three key/value pairs. This hashmap object is a part of another java model object which just has ordinary fields namely: name (String) and id number(int). I then converted the output of a method that has an object, which includes the two fields and the hashmap object, into a json object to be used in javascript.

The problem is that I can access the name and id fields in javascript by using the dot accessor I.e. obj.name and obj.id but I don’t know how to access the information from the hashmap separately which was converted to json because the key/values don’t have named fields.

When I use the the dot accessor and put in the name of the hashmap object (in other words obj.student where ‘student’ is the name of the hashmap) it gives me both the key and values i.e name of student “Paul” and grade ‘9’ (the hasmap has String for names and int for grades).

What I’d like is to be able to access both key and values separately as I want to use then in a chart js chart.

```
for (var i=0; i<jsonString.length; i++) {
     let obj = jsonString[i];
     xValues[i] = obj.name;
     yValues[i] = obj.id;
     const myJSON = JSON.stringify(obj.student);
     xValuesOne[i] = myJSON;
}
```

The above code works for extracting the name and id properties but for the student property, as it was a hashmap in java, the specific values don’t have names that I can use to extract the properties.

The string part should be the students name (x-axis) and the int part of the hashmap should be their grade (y-axis).

At the moment in relation to the student data, xValuesOne[i] produces both the string (name) and int (grade) in the x-axis. I would like to extract both the string and the int separately and place them in different axis for chart js.

Any ideas on how to do this?

Comment: Please add some paragraph structure to your question... The wall of text it is now, is hard to read.

Comment: Show us the json please.

Comment: @Cerbus. Sure.  1. I created a java pojo with the following fields: name, id and with a hashmap called student (String=name, int=students’ grade).
2. Based on the above class, I created an object which holds data in their respective fields in android studio.

Students studentOne = new Students(); studentOne.setName("Tom"); studentOne.setId(234567); studentOne.student.put(“Tom”,9);

Comment: 3. I then placed the above (2) into a java method which  converts the object into a json to be used in javascript.  public String getFromAndroid() {
Students studentOne = new Students(); studentOne.setName("Tom"); studentOne.setId(234567); studentOne.student.put(“Tom”,9);

ArrayList<Student> students = new ArrayList(); students.add(studentOne); students.add(studentTwo); students.add(studentThree);  Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create(); String jsonObjArray = ""; String jsonObj = gson.toJson(pickers);  return jsonObj;
}

Comment: 4 Now in javascript I get the json from android studio, convert it to a javascript object and loop through the data to be used in a chart js bar chart.

var xValues = []; var yValues = []; var xValuesOne = []; var yValuesOne = []; var stringList = null;         stringList = Android.getFromAndroid();         var jsonString = JSON.parse(stringList);          for (var i=0; i<jsonString.length; i++) {             let obj = jsonString[i];             xValues[i] = obj.name;             yValues[i] = obj.id;         const myJSON = JSON.stringify(obj.student);         xValuesOne[i] = myJSON;        }

Comment: 5 the problem is that I don’t know how to extract the data that I placed into the hashmap into separate variables to be used in an x-axis and y-axis bar chart just like what I did in 4(above) for the name and id data. The code compiles. The data in the student hashmap prints  all of the hashmap data on one line (Tom,8, Sally, 5, Peter, 3). I want to extract the name property from the hashmap and place this in one variable and the grade property (int) in the hashmap into another variable. If I can do this, I’ll be able to produce a chart.